# Dynamically assign background of div to blend in with background of body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of divs, each of which rotate to reveal another div. Currently the "front" divs have no background, but this makes the transition pretty bad (nothing happens, text goes away, backface is revealed). I'd like to assign them a background based on the portion of  background they cover so that they will blend in but change when rotating. I'm not sure how to get the correct location of the background image.

HTML:

```
<section class='grid-1'>
   <div class='day-1'>
       <label>
           <div class='door'>
             <div class='front'>1</div>
             <div class='back'></div>
           </div>
       </label>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: url(...) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.day-1 .front{
    background: url(...) no-repeat var(--offset-x) var(--offset-y);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const setBgTest = () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = [...];
    const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day-1');
    const day = days[0];
    const dayRect = day.getBoundingClientRect();
    const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offX = ((dayRect.x-bodyRect.x)/document.body.clientWidth)*img.naturalWidth;
    const offY = ((dayRect.y-bodyRect.y)/document.body.clientHeight)*img.naturalHeight;
}
setBgTest();
```

(This will be turned into a loop for all days and invoked on window resize)

This doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to calculate the correct offsets.

Updated: Calculates percentage offset within body and uses that percentage of original image size. It's close, but not quite right.

Comment: [`background-position`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/)?

Comment: @GhostPengy I'm using the [background shorthand](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp), so it's included. My problem is calculating the offsets.

Comment: The question is unclear, what you mean with "rotate"? How the background blending (which suggest the question is about colors) is related to a rotation? Can you please provide the full code?

Comment: @Daniels118 The rotation is an irrelevant detail, really (and is handled by [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)). What I'm trying to do is have the background of an element match with the background of the body at the same coordinates. Basically calculating the background-position to line up with the page. All relevant code for this is included.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have the same image on both the divs and body, but the divs only contain a subarea of the body image and you want this subarea matches the body background at the same position. So the actual wrong behaviour is ![this](https://i.ibb.co/9ZC8kcr/test.png), can you confirm?

Comment: @Daniels118 Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

Well, you just added `background-size: cover`, so it's now clear your background size is dynamic. Since javascript can't know directly the size of the background you have to mimic the cover behaviour yourself, this can be achieved with the following steps:

1. download the original image through javascript to know its original size;
2. compute the scaling to let the image fit in the window;
3. apply the scaling to all the doors background along with the offset as in my previous answer.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(function() {
    var background = $('body');
    var bgImg = background.css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
    const img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function() {
        var resizeHandler = function() {
            var bgw = window.innerWidth;
            var bgh = bgw * img.height / img.width;
            background.css('background-size', bgw+'px '+bgh+'px');
            var bgPos = background.offset();
            bgPos.left -= parseInt(background.css('marginLeft'), 10);
            bgPos.top -= parseInt(background.css('marginTop'), 10);
            $('.day-1 .front').each(function() {
                var elem = $(this);
                var pos = elem.offset();
                var x = pos.left - bgPos.left;
                var y = pos.top - bgPos.top;
                elem.css('background-position', (-x)+'px '+(-y)+'px');
                elem.css('background-size', bgw+'px '+bgh+'px');
            });
        };
        $(window).resize(resizeHandler);
        resizeHandler();
    });
    img.src = bgImg;
});
```

```css
body {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/d2DJp02/wallpaper-2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.door {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 120px;
}

.door>div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 120px;
}

.day-1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 90px;
}

.day-1 .front {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/d2DJp02/wallpaper-2.jpg') no-repeat;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.door:hover .front {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotateY(85deg);
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.day-1 .back {
    background: black url('https://i.ibb.co/rZW5T2v/dog.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='grid-1'>
           <div class='day-1'>
               <label>
                   <div class='door'>
                     <div class='back'></div>
                     <div class='front'>1</div>
                   </div>
               </label>
           </div>
        </section>
```

**Old answer**

I've arranged this code using jquery, but you can rewrite using pure javascript. You can use the "offset" method to know where an element is within the document. If you subtract the door coordinates from the main element (the one which contains the whole background) coordinates, then you get the relative coordinates. Then just apply them as negative background-position:

```js
$(function() {
    var background = $('.grid-1');
    var bgPos = background.offset();
    var elem = $('.day-1 .front');
    var elemPos = elem.offset();
    var relPos = {left: elemPos.left - bgPos.left, top: elemPos.top - bgPos.top};
    elem.css('background-position', (-relPos.left)+'px '+(-relPos.top)+'px');
});
```

```css
.grid-1 {
    height: 300px;
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/d2DJp02/wallpaper-2.jpg') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 400px 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.door {
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 120px;
}

.door>div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 120px;
}

.day-1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 90px;
}

.day-1 .front {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/d2DJp02/wallpaper-2.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px 300px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.door:hover .front {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotateY(85deg);
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.day-1 .back {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/rZW5T2v/dog.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='grid-1'>
   <div class='day-1'>
       <label>
           <div class='door'>
             <div class='back'></div>
             <div class='front'>1</div>
           </div>
       </label>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That works beautifully for background of .grid-1, but I can't get it to work for the background of body (changing background to the <body> and adding offsets rather than subtracting).

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for the `background: cover;` mistake, I did not realize the functionality. I made some minor changes to handle when images are wider than the window (though it does not handle when the document is wider than the window).